# get exact values which are tested in jest

Tags: jestjs, automated-tests, ts-jest

I have this test with Jest which works but I would like to print what exactly is the value tested by "toBeinstanceOf"

```
it('tests /destinations endpoints', async () => {

        await expect(chercheData()).resolves.toBeInstanceOf(Object);

    });
```

How can I do that ? I took an example with a promise but It could be any other case.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the exact output you get? I think Jest _does_ show the actual value (`Received value:`) when that assertion fails. Give a [mre].

Comment: Hi, I get this :
```
> jest

 PASS  src/test/space.spec.ts
  Space test suite
    √ My Space Test (9 ms)
    √ tests /destinations endpoints (91 ms)
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.457 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: It's not going to print _any_ diff if the expectation succeeds.

Comment: ok thank you sorry, that was a stupid question